# A NOT-NULL column of type TIMESTAMP without a default value in MySQL

Tags: mysql

If I create a table

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (
    id BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    createDate TIMESTAMP(3) NOT NULL,
    updateDate TIMESTAMP(3) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    closeDate TIMESTAMP(3) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
)  ENGINE=INNODB;
```

`createDate` column is created as

```
`createDate` timestamp(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(3) ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(3),
```

1) What is the logic behind this? Why MySQL adds the default value? And why it adds `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(3)`?

2) Is it possible to create a column `timestamp(3) NOT NULL` without the default value?

**EDIT1:**

I have an impression that `id` column, for example, does not have a default value, because if I do

```
insert t1 updateDate values (now());
```

I get

```
ERROR 1364 (HY000): Field 'id' doesn't have a default value
```

so the default value is not added automatically to a column of INT type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all: Every column has a default value. In many cases this default value is `NULL`, but if declared `NOT NULL` it must obviously be something else.

With the `TIMESTAMP` data type, the default value is `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()`, but of course this can be overwritten:

```
createDate TIMESTAMP(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-01-01 00:00:00'
```

will e.g. set a default value of 0.0 A.D.

Comment: Are you sure that `Every column has a default value`? If I try `insert t1 (updateDate) values (now());` I get `ERROR 1364 (HY000): Field 'id' doesn't have a default value`

Comment: The default value is `NULL`, but this is forbidden

Comment: Why I cannot have this `forbidden NULL default value` with a column of type TIMESTAMP?

Comment: Because MySQL choses to handle timestamps different than other data types: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/timestamp-initialization.html